# Improving performance of A* search in PHP

Tags: php, breadth-first-search

I need to figure out what can be done to improve the performance of a A* search algorithm in PHP. The idea is to look for the shortest path, in number of hops, between two points in a "map". Actual distance is irrelevant.

This is a minimalistic functional version of what I'm doing:

```
<?php

    /*

        1 ____ 2 ____ 3 ___ 5
        | \            ____/|
        |  \    ______/     |
        |   4__/            |
        |  /                7
        | /                 
        6                   

    */

    $points = [
        1 => [2, 4, 6],
        2 => [1, 3],
        3 => [2, 5],
        4 => [1, 5, 6],
        5 => [3, 4, 7],
        6 => [1, 4],
        7 => [5]
    ];

    function points_pathfind($from, $to)
    {
        global $points;

        if (!isset($points[$from]) || !isset($points[$to]))
            return null;

        if ($from == $to)
            return [$from];

        $seen = [$from];  // improves peformance
        $queue = [];
        $step = [$from, null];
        for (;;)
        {
            if ($queue)
            {
                $step = array_shift($queue);
                if ($step[0] == $to)
                {
                    $result = [];
                    while ($step !== null)
                    {
                        $result[] = $step[0];
                        $step = $step[1];
                    }
                    return array_reverse($result);
                }
            }
            foreach ($points[$step[0]] as $point)
            {
                if (!in_array($point, $seen))
                {
                    $seen[]  = $point;
                    $queue[] = [$point, $step];
                }
            }

            if (!$queue)
                return null;
        }
    }

    echo implode(' -=> ', points_pathfind(1, 7));
```

Output:

> 1 -=> 4 -=> 5 -=> 7

The actual code howover will deal with almost 8000 points with a total of over 15000 connections, in which it all become extremely slow to the point that mapping some paths can take a couple seconds. This is unacceptable to my application. I even considered caching all possibilities to a database (which I will have to do anyway) but it is so slow it would take days only to generate this cache. I'm sure its performance can be improved somehow, I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Is it always going to be a simple 2D array, or will you have to deal with higher levels of recursion?

Comment: It is as simple as this example is, the only thing that changes is the high number of points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to greatly increase performance by avoiding array resizing and memory reallocation. By allocating all array space I need by start and reusing those arrays instead of recreating and resizing them, the performance of the code has dramatically changed from one search every couple seconds to almost a hundred searches per second.

```
<?php

    /*

        1 ____ 2 ____ 3 ___ 5
        | \            ____/|
        |  \    ______/     |
        |   4__/            |
        |  /                7
        | /                 
        6                   

    */

    $points = [
        1 => [2, 4, 6],
        2 => [1, 3],
        3 => [2, 5],
        4 => [1, 5, 6],
        5 => [3, 4, 7],
        6 => [1, 4],
        7 => [5]
    ];

    $seen = $queue = [];
    foreach ($points as $key => $val)
    {
        $seen[$key] = 0;
        $queue[] = [0, -1];
    }

    function points_pathfind($from, $to)
    {
        global $points, $seen, $queue;

        if (!isset($points[$from]) || !isset($points[$to]))
            return null;

        if ($from == $to)
            return [$from];

        $queue[0][0] = $from;

        array_walk($seen, function (&$a) { $a = 0; });
        $seen[$from] = 1;

        for ($cur = $end = 0; $cur <= $end; ++$cur)    
        {
            foreach ($points[$queue[$cur][0]] as $next)
            {
                if (!$seen[$next])
                {
                    if ($next == $to)
                    {
                        $result = [$to];
                        for ($jmp = $cur; $jmp != -1; $jmp = $queue[$jmp][1])
                            $result[] = $queue[$jmp][0];
                        return array_reverse($result);
                    }

                    ++$end;
                    $seen[$next]    = 1;
                    $queue[$end][0] = $next;
                    $queue[$end][1] = $cur;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo implode(' -=> ', points_pathfind(1, 7));
```

The general approach of the algorithm howover is still the same. I wonder if there is a more intelligent way.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get one thing straight first of all:

## This is not A*

In A*, there is a famous calculation of \$f = g + h\$. The \$g\$ is the cost for all the steps taken so far (in your case this cost function would simply return \$1\$), while the \$h\$ is pretty much the key: It's a heuristic function to *estimate* how much is left. This is often done using [*Manhattan Distance*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). As your points is not in a grid system from what I can understand, making a useful heuristic function is significantly harder.

## Tell, don't ask

```
global $points;
```

This little piece of code violates the principle of *Tell, don't ask*. You should tell a function what it needs to know in order to do it's job, *the method should not ask the outside world about this information*. It would be much better to pass the `$points` variable to the function, just like the other ones.

## Calculating the buffered values

Let's say that you have calculated the distance between 4 to 7, and you're currently calculating 1 to 7. Then it's only necessary to calculate the distance between 1 and 4. Then you know how far the remaining distance is as well.

Whether or not it is useful to cache the distances at all depends on how often they are changing. As you are considering caching it, I assume that it does not change too often.

## Suggested reading

Artificial Intelligence - foundations of computational agents [Chapter 3 - States and Searching](http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_46.html)

Comment: I cannot buffer 4 to 7 and simply assume it when searching 1 to 7, there is no guarantee that the shortest path from 1 to 7 envolves 4,  I have to verify that.

Comment: Also, I generated a table with all possible paths so I could fetch the information directly from a MySQL query, however the table with this cache exceeded 63GB in file size, with a number of rows I couldn't even determine because `SELECT COUNT(1)` was timing out. I suppose this experience gives an idea of how memory consuming it would be to buffer those "path predictions".

Comment: @Havenard When you are caching it, are you caching all nodes to all nodes? How many connections does each node have on average and as maximum? What is it that you are trying to map here? What does each node represent? Of course there is no guarantee that the shortest path from 1 to 7 goes through 4, but if it does then you don't need to recalculate the path from 4 to 7, because you already know what the shortest path between 4 to 7 is.

Comment: Also: Would using different scales of nodes help? Many pathfinding algorithms tries to first find a connection between cluster A and cluster B, and then once inside cluster B it searches on a more detailed level.

Comment: Connections range from 1 to about 6, but most have 2 or 3. There are 8000 nodes with 15000 connections total. Maximum number of jumps is 64 I think. I cached the nodes as ids in a table the format `from INT, to INT, path TEXT` where path is a list of ids separated by space. By the morning the job was done, my hard drive almost ran out of space.

Comment: Unfortunately there isnt really a heuristic applicable here, even though the nodes have coordinates associated with them, the connections are rarely related to its nearest neighbors, and all that matters is the number of hops.

Comment: @Havenard As I don't have more context, I can only recommend looking into clustering algorithms. If all 8000 nodes needs to check all other 7999 nodes, that gets very complex very quickly. If you would organize them into clusters then I think it could make things easier for you in the future. You might also want to look into the option of using an external tool, such as [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html) to do the job for you (or parts of it).

Comment: Yeah, I might have to write a PHP module to have this implemented in C, but for now my ~90 searches per second is sufficing.

Comment: @Havenard (clicked the wrong button) I'm glad to hear that.